# How to give css background-image location in laravel

Tags: css, laravel

i want to give location of background image inside css file but it is showing invalid

tried but not showing

```
 css file
 background: url{{('image/clock-background.jpeg')}}), center no-repeat;
```

background image should be loaded

Comment: sorry the file was inside public/css/home/main.css

Comment: and the image is in public/image/clock-background-jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly used like that

```
background: url('image/clock-background.jpeg'), center no-repeat;
```

or if you want to [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset) helper function then you used like that:

```
background: url("{{ asset('image/clock-background.jpeg') }}")
```

Comment: sorry the file was inside public/css/home/main.css

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url{{('image/clock-background.jpeg')}}), center no-repeat;
```

is missing a ( after 'url'. Also get rid of the comma. Replace it with:

```
background: url({{('image/clock-background.jpeg')}}) center no-repeat;
```

Comment: sorry the file was inside public/css/home/main.css

Comment: @atifaslam if this code comes from a .css file it will not work anyway. Because you can only use {{ }} in .blade.php files

Comment: picture is in public/image/clock-background-jpeg

Comment: @atifaslam you could create a blade subview, in which you put a <style> tag. Within that style tag you put your code. Then just import your subview with the 'include' blade function. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#including-sub-views

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url('/image/clock-background.jpeg');
```

Should work